# Cannot retrieve existing row with uuid primary key using python and flask

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, uuid

I have recently stumbled upon a problem when I wanted to retrieve a row from the table by passing uuid parameter in flask.

Whenever I pass firstname or other parameter than **UUID** it retrieves the row. When I pass **UUID** in a query it retrieves **None**.
Here is my ***view.py*** file.

```
    @bp.route('/citizen-info/<uuid:id>')
    def citizen_info(id):
        citizen = citizen_access.get_citizen_info(id)
        return render_template('citizen/citizen_info.html', citizen=citizen)
```

And my **citizen_access.py** file:

```
    def get_citizen_info(id):
        citizen_info = db.session.query(Subject).filter(Subject.id == id)
        return citizen_info.first()
```

I tried to put `<string:id>`, `<uuid:id>`, `<id>` in ***url*** but none of them worked, I tried to cast the `id` in my controller as a `str(id)` and as `uuid.UUID(id)` with no luck.
Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Note: I use ***python and flask***, and my database is ***postgres***.

Comment: hope you referred this -- https://pypi.org/project/Flask-UUID/

Comment: Hi @Codenewbie I didn't use Flask-UUID in my project.

Comment: I used Flask-UUID and the same error persists. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'firstname' I don't know why it does this I have the row with the specific id. I checked it thousand times...:/

Comment: sorry I am unable to help you out , but have you tried printing id and citizen_info ? Just to see if they are as you thought

Comment: Yes I did that and id was displayed as expected. I dunno why it cannot retrieve the data everything seems fine but None is returned..

Comment: let's try with `citizen_info.all()` instead of `first()` as the docs say `first()` Return the first result of this Query or None if the result doesn’t contain any row.

Comment: I tried it as well. Still didn't returns None..

Comment: So, there is no data.

Comment: None is returned. Actually there is a data with the specified uuid in database. But nothing is returned when I pass the uuid to the query shown above..

Comment: Can you extract and post the actual SQL statement generated and sent to db server. Also post the actual table ddl from postgres.

Comment: You should try hard code a UUID into the query and see if it returns anything. Then you can exclude or focus on the URL route parsing as the source of the problem; or confirm it is missing data.